# vector assign in Cython

Tags: python, pointers, vector, cython

Here is my program of cython

```
cdef struct Node:
    int v
    Node* next
    Node* pre

def f(int N):
    cdef:
        vector[Node*] narray
        int i
    narray.assign(N, 0)
    for i in xrange(N):
        narray[i] = 0
```

Cython compiling result:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef:
        vector[Node*] narray
        int i
    narray.assign(N, 0)
    for i in xrange(N):
        narray[i] = 0
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

testLinkList.pyx:107:14: Compiler crash in AnalyseExpressionsTransform
```

But I can use `push_back()` to append values at the end of the vector or use `int` instead of `Node*`.
What is wrong?

Comment: "Compiler crash" means a bug. Submit a bug report to the cython-users ML or their GitHub.

Comment: does it make a difference to write narray[i] = NULL, or reinterpret_cast<Node*>(0) ?  (though agreed with larsmans to report this as a bug, since it is presented as a compiler crash)

Comment: They don't have enabled their issue tracker on Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Cython are you using?  Version 0.20.1 works for me with this code:

```
# distutils: language=c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef struct Node:
    int v
    Node* next
    Node* pre

def f(int N):
    cdef:
        vector[Node*] narray
        int i
    narray.assign(N, NULL)
    for i in range(N):
        narray[i] = NULL
```

And with this `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("test_vector.pyx"))
```